# Array , Modification Split words in array independently

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

```js
/**
  @this is my question , how can i make this
  var arrayItem = [" foxy  jennifer "];
  
  to this
  
  var arrayItem = ["foxy","jennifer"];
  
**/

var arrayItem = [" foxy  jennifer "];
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Still figuring out , how to make strings of words in array , to an independent item in the array anyone has an idea on how to make that happen thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `split()` and `filter()`:

```js
var arrayItem = [" foxy  jennifer "];
arrayItem = arrayItem[0].split(' ').filter(i => i);
console.log(arrayItem);
```

The [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method splits a String object into an array of strings by separating the string into substrings, using a specified separator string to determine where to make each split.

The [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function. Here just removing all the empty string from the array.

**OR:** You can do the following if you do not want to use `filter()`:

```js
var arrayItem = [" foxy  jennifer "];
arrayItem = arrayItem[0].trim().split(/\s+/);
console.log(arrayItem);
```

Comment: why the filter?

Comment: @Mamun Yeah I just realized `""` returns false lol. But your solution will only work if `arrayItem` contains only one item. And you don't need to iterate over the array using a filter. Take a look at my suggested edit and you'll see what I mean`

Comment: @Mamun Here's the suggested edit I was talking about https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19583419

Answer (score 0):

Here's the way I would do it explained in detail.

```js
let arrayItem = [" foxy jennifer "];

function extractWords(strList) {
  // If strList is a string transform it into an array
  if(typeof strList === 'string')
    strList = [strList];
  // If strList is still not an array throw an error
  if(!Array.isArray(strList))
    throw 'strList must be an array';
  // more validations....
    
  // Once the validations are done,
  
  let result; // Will be our resulting array of words
  
  // If strList contains only one string
  if(strList.length === 1) {
    result = strList[0].trim().split(/\s+/);
    /* trim removes the spaces at both ends of a string */
    
    /* split allows to split a string where the 
    specified string or RegExp matches */
    
    /* /\s+/ is our RegExp where \s means a space 
    and \s+ means we want to match/replace 1 or more 
    consecutive space so the string will be splitted 
    everywhere one or more spaces are found */
    
    /* For example, "a b c d " would become ["a", "b", "c", "d"] 
    and notice that the trailing space is removed by the trim 
    which prevents from getting this ["a", "b", "c", "d", ""]
    cause we dont want empty string in our array of words */
  } else {
    // Now, if strList has more than 1 string in it
    // The reduce wont work with only one string in the array
    
    // The following is a bit more complex
    
    /* reduce will pass through every string string exactly 
    like map or forEach except that 2 elements will be passed 
    to the callback function */
    result = strList.reduce(function(arg1, arg2) {
      /* The first time the callback is called, 
      arg1 will contain the first element of the array 
      but for all the next calls to the callback arg1 will contain 
      the previous call result. The whole reduce will return the 
      last result */
      /* arg2 will contains the next element in the array exactly 
      like the first argument of forEach */
      
      /* Since we want an array of words as final result we will 
      want to transform arg1 into an array */
      
      /* Here we check if arg1 is an array cause on the first call 
      arg1 will be the first element of strList and wont be an array */
      if(!Array.isArray(arg1)) {
        // Here split will return an array
        arg1 = arg1.trim().split(/\s+/);
      }
      /* We dont transform arg2 into an array since it wont 
      be passed as any argument on the next call instead on the next call arg2
      will be the next element of the array */
      
      /* The value we will return here will be the value of arg1 on 
      the next call */
      /* Here we return concatenation the previous results with an array 
      of words contained in arg2 */
      return arg1.concat(arg2.trim().split(/\s+/));
    });
    /* The final result is an array with all the words of every string in strList */
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(extractWords([" this  is  ", "just an    ", "example"]));
console.log(extractWords(arrayItem));
```

Tell me if there's anything you still don't understand and I'll explain it